# Enviar formulário angular

Tags: angular

Bom estou enviando um formulário via angular, mais os dados não estão chegando atualizado no backend?

```
<form [formGroup]="categoriaForm" (ngSubmit)="salvarCategoria()">
  <tr *ngFor="let data of config; let i = index;" class="d-flex">
    <td class="col-1">{{i}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="_" formControlName="pos" [value]="data.pos" maxlength="7"></td>
    <td class="col-5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{data.legend}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="_" formControlName="limit" [value]="data.limit" maxlength="7"></td>
  </tr>
</form>
<br><a (click)="categoriaAtualizar()">send</a>
```

[Link do problema também como referencia](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jk5cos?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opa arrumei aqui pra vc veja no meu stackblits,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yeqm1j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Primeiro vc não precisa do value e do max-length. Voce pode fazer a validacao quando cria e o valor da esquerda que esta '' e o valor incial. Se vcquiser mudar o valor vc pode fazer form.setValue(...), Segundo sua estrutra do form esta errada como vc tem um array vc precisa o formArray pra criar o formgroup pra cada elemento.

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public config: any = [{ id: "basic1", legend: "Basic 1", limit: 3, pos: 1 },
  { id: "basic2", legend: "Basic 2", limit: 3, pos: 2 },
  { id: "basic3", legend: "Basic 3", limit: 3, pos: 3 }];
  categoriaForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoriaForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      items: this.formBuilder.array([this.createFormGroup(), this.createFormGroup(), this.createFormGroup()])
    });;
    console.log(this.items)
  }

  get items(): FormArray {
    return this.categoriaForm.get('items') as FormArray;
  }

  createFormGroup() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      pos: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(7)]],
      limit: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(7)]]
    });

  }
  categoriaAtualizar() {
    const configToStore = {
      ...this.config,
      ...this.categoriaForm.value
    }
    console.log(configToStore);
  }
}
```

html

```
<form [formGroup]="categoriaForm">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items.controls; let i = index;">
        <tr class="d-flex" [formGroup]="item">
            <td class="col-1">{{i}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; pos</td>
            <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="pos"></td>
                <td class="col-1">{{i}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; limit</td>
            <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="limit"></td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</form>
<br>
<a (click)="categoriaAtualizar()">send</a>

{{items.value|json}}
```

Comment: perfeito... tentei entender o formBuilder.array mas não consegui... brigado por ensinar