# Form builder com array no angular

Tags: angular

Preciso criar um form que incrementa dinamicamente três campos ao clicar em um botão.

Procurei no site do angular mas lá só mostra como faz com um campo.

Tentei algo como:

```
    <div formArrayName="variacoes">
      <div *ngFor="let variacao of variacoes.controls; let i=index">
        <label for="i">
          Nome Variação:
          <input [formControlName]="i" type="text" id="i" class="form-control">
        </label>

        <label for="i">
          Valor:
          <input [formControlName]="i" type="text" id="i" class="form-control">
        </label>

        <label for="i">
          SKU
          <input [formControlName]="i" type="text" id="i" class="form-control">
        </label>

      </div>
    </div>
```

produtoForm = this.fb.group({
    variacoes: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control(''),
    ])
  });

Minhas funções:

```
get variacoes() {
    return this.produtoForm.get('variacoes') as FormArray;
  }

  addVariacao() {
    this.variacoes.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
```

A ideia seria que meu form tivesse um objeto chamado variacoes que dentro dele tem arrays com chave descricao, valor e sku.

@Atualização:

Não está adicionando novos campos como esperado, está atualizando os campos existentes:

```
      <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        <button (click)="addVariacao()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect"><i class="fa fa-plus-square create-icon"
            aria-hidden="true"></i>Adicionar variação</button>
      </div>

      <form [formGroup]="categoriaForm">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of variacoes.controls; let i = index;">
          <tr class="d-flex" [formGroup]="item">
            <td class="col-1 primary-color">{{i}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; descricao</td>
            <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="descricao"></td>
              <td class="col-1 primary-color">{{i}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; valor</td>
            <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="valor"></td>
            <td class="col-3"><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="sku"></td>
            <td class="col-1 primary-color">{{i}}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Sku</td>
          </tr>
        </ng-container>
      </form>

  ngOnInit() {
    this.categoriaForm = this.fb.group({

    variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])

    });

  get variacoes(): FormArray {
    return this.categoriaForm.get('variacoes') as FormArray;
  }

  addVariacao(){
    this.categoriaForm = this.fb.group({
      variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])
    });;
  }

  createFormGroup() {
    return this.fb.group({
      descricao: [''],
      valor: [''],
      sku: ['']
    });
  }
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327124/enviar-formul%C3%A1rio-angular/327190#327190

Comment: fiz isso a esses dias atras

Comment: qualquer duvida só falar

Comment: retornou ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in

Comment: public variacoes: any = [{descricao : "descricao1", valor: "valor1", sku: 'sku1' }]
  categoriaForm: FormGroup;

Comment: e no template:       <form [formGroup]="categoriaForm">

Comment: Da uma olhada nesse meu stackblitz que eu fiz na resposta do willian

Comment: editei a pergunta com atualização, se puder dar uma olhada...

Comment: entao seguinte esse campo e dinamico? vem de uma db? se for da uma add no array variacoes.controls que ele vai fica dinamico com um push

Comment: tenho la em casa isso feito... se não conseguir te passo assim que chegar la

Comment: se nao me engano e isso aki https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934396/angular-4-patchvalue-based-on-index-in-formarray , tem ate o remove

Comment: Tentei:   addVariacao(){
    this.categoriaForm.patchValue({
      variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])
    });
  }

Não deu certo... value.foreach is not a function

Comment: tenta assim this.variacoes.at(index).patchValue({descricao:'teste', valor:1, sku:0}); index deria a posição do novo array da um this.variacoes?.lenght e coloca o valor no lugar do index ve se funciona

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public formulario;
```

`public ngOnInit() {
    this.formulario = new FormGroup({
      data: new FormControl(),
      nome: new FormControl(),
      tipos: new FormBuilder().array([
        new FormGroup({
          id: new FormControl(),
          nome: new FormControl(),
        }),
      ])
    });
  }`

```
  public adicionarForm() {
this.formulario.controls.tipos.controls.push(
  new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(),
    nome: new FormControl(),
  }),
);
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Brother, sempre que você tenta adicionar mais uma variação você acaba substituindo todo o conteudo por apenas uma:

```
addVariacao() {
    this.categoriaForm = this.fb.group({
        variacoes: this.fb.array([this.createFormGroup()])
});
```

Basta apenas você adicionar mais um item no FormArray, como qualquer array, utilizando a função `.push()`:

```
addVariacao() {
    this.variacoes.push(this.createFormGroup())
}
```

Aqui tem um exemplo do código funcionando, espero que eu tenha ajudado. xD

https://stackblitz.com/edit/simple-dynamic-form-builder-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts